# Angular add custom .css files to Angular-CLI project

Tags: css, angular

I'm adding existing .js and .css files to an Angular 4 app which uses angular-cli 1.0.6. Until a recent upgrade, I was simply referencing them in index.html--I know that's 'wrong' but it worked for my current needs.

After a recent update, I'm getting 404s for everything I've tried. I have managed to add the JavaScript file by adding it to angular-cli.json and then importing it into a component. That's working, but the same isn't working for the .css file.

I've tried it in index.html: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/test.css">`
I've tried in the component's template: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../app/scripts/test.css">`
And I've tried adding it the to styles in the component: `styleUrls: ['../edit.scss', '../../scripts/test.css'],`

I'm getting 404s for all of them even though the paths are valid (I can follow them in the editor).

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An angular-cli project contains by default a `styles.css` file under the `src` folder of the project (`myAngularCliProjectName/src/styles.css`).
In this file you'll be able to add global styles and also import other style files.
There's no need at all to link them from the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 8):

Go to your angular-cli.json file and there is a property of arrays and you can add your css file in that place, just like I did with bootsrap.min.css.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I tried that. As I mentioned in the question adding it in angular-cli.json didn't help. But to be clear, after I've added it there, how do I include in a certain component template but not globally?