# How to link an external stylesheet to angular

Tags: angular

in index.html of my angular app I am adding

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" type="text/css"  />
```

When I build the project I get error

Generating index html...Unable to locate stylesheet: /home/myproj/https:/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css

Comment: If you want use bootstrap control then it is better to install bootstrap and then use the controls. Please check the [documentation] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap). However, if you still want to use that *.css file then you can do that in angular.json file . Please check the links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220569/angular-add-custom-css-files-to-angular-cli-project/44221796), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667320/how-to-add-custom-css-files-globally-for-angular-6-project).

Comment: you can use the angular.json -in the part of "styles" is an array just before styles.css-

Comment: @Eliseo is that the preferred way to using the styles.scss file?

Comment: If I put that in angular.json then I have to install the css on my server. That works but  I could not link to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com...    Is  the only way is to install  the css on the local server ?  Can you please show via an example?  I do not want to download it on my server but would like to link to  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com...